# Reproducing a population. Should I `deepcopy` each individual?

Tags: copy, sample, julia, deep-copy, random

I simulate an evolving population in Julia. Somewhere in my code I randomly sample (sample weighted by the `fitnesses` of the individuals) individuals in order to form the next generation. Because the same individual can be sampled several times (sampling with replacement), I have to make that I copy the individuals and not only create a new pointer to the same data. Here is what the code looks like for the moment:

```
##### Reproduction ######
NewPopulation = Array(Individuals, nb_individuals_in_population)
fitnesses = WeightVec(fitnesses)
for i = 1:nb_individuals_in_population
    NewPopulation[i] = deepcopy(sample(OldPopulation, fitnesses))
end
```

, where `Individuals` is a `type` made of two arrays of `true/false`

**Is there a more performant (faster) way to simulate reproduction?**

My main doubt is that when I `deepcopy` more data than I need to `deepcopy`. Some `Individuals` will be sampled only once, so I would not need to `deepcopy` them. Should I not deepcopying, and then search for individuals that are in multiple copies in the `NewPopulation` in order to `deepcopy` them? Do you think I would gain time? Is there a faster solution? Also, there might have a better alternative to the way I sample individuals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you only need to copy if the different copies will later mutate in different ways. If there's just breeding and selection with no mutation, then a reference to the "copied" individual would be sufficient.

FYI `deepcopy` is (in currently julia releases) slow; if you need performance, you should write a specific `copy` method for your type(s).

Comment: Oh interesting. I will make a specific copy method then. Yes, individuals can mutate, so it is necessary to deepcopy the individuals that are found in more than one copy at the next generation.

Answer (score 2):

While you could possibly gain some time by only `deepcopy`ing the ones that are sampled multiple times, I'm fairly sure that this will not be the slow part of your algorithm (I'd expect it to be the fitness evaluation function).

Also, it does depend somewhat on what an `Individual` is precisely. If all the fields are just `immutables` themselves, like floats, then maybe make `Individual` `immutable` too. If it has fields that are, e.g. `Matrix{Float64}`, this isn't going to work and `deepcopy` is needed.

Comment: Thank you. I am interested in simulating small genomes over many generation, so it might be possible that the slow part is not necessarily the fitness calculation. But I haven't verified that. The `Individuals` are made of two arrays of true/false (I edited my post to add this info).

Comment: You could use the in-built profiler to determine what is slow and what isn't - could be insightful.