# Speed up deepcopy for new type

Tags: julia

**Question:** I have a new type `type MyFloat; x::Float64 ; end`. I want to perform a `deepcopy` on a `Vector{MyFloat}`. Using Julia v0.5.0 on Ubuntu 16.04, the operation runs roughly 150 times slower than a `deepcopy` call on an equivalent length `Vector{Float64}`. Is it possible to speed up a `deepcopy` on my `Vector{MyFloat}`?

**Code snippet:** The 150 times slowdown can be seen with the following code snippet which can be pasted to the REPL:

```
#Just my own floating point type
type MyFloat
    x::Float64
end

#This function performs N deepcopy operations on a Vector{MyFloat} of length J
function f1(J::Int, N::Int)
    v = MyFloat.(rand(J))
    x = [ deepcopy(v) for n = 1:N ]
end

#The same as f1, but on Vector{Float64} instead of Vector{MyFloat}
function f2(J::Int, N::Int)
    v = rand(J)
    x = [ deepcopy(v) for n = 1:N ]
end

#Pre-compilation step
f1(2, 2);
f2(2, 2);

#Timings
@time f1(100, 15000);
@time f2(100, 15000);
```

On my machine this produces:

```
julia> @time f1(100, 15000);
  1.944410 seconds (4.61 M allocations: 167.888 MB, 7.72% gc time)

julia> @time f2(100, 15000);
  0.013513 seconds (45.01 k allocations: 19.113 MB, 78.80% gc time)
```

Looking at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28183232/reproducing-a-population-should-i-deepcopy-each-individual) it sounds like I can speed things up by defining my own `copy` method for `MyFloat`. I've tried things like:

```
Base.deepcopy(x::MyFloat)::MyFloat = MyFloat(x.x);
Base.deepcopy(v::Vector{MyFloat})::Vector{MyFloat} = [ MyFloat(y.x) for y in v ]
Base.copy(x::MyFloat)::MyFloat = MyFloat(x.x)
Base.copy(v::Vector{MyFloat})::Vector{MyFloat} = [ MyFloat(y.x) for y in v ]
```

but this doesn't make any difference.

**Final note:** Letting `a = MyFloat.([1.0, 2.0])`, I could just use `b = copy(a)` and there is no speed penalty. This is fine, as long as I am careful to only ever do operations like `b[1] = MyFloat(3.0)` (which will modify `b` but not `a`). But if I get sloppy and accidentally write `b[1].x = 3.0`, then this will modify both `a` and `b`.

By the way, it is entirely possible that I do not have a deep understanding of the differences between `copy` and `deepcopy`... I have read [this](http://www.stochasticlifestyle.com/7-julia-gotchas-handle/) great blog post (thanks @ChrisRackauckas), but I'm certainly a bit fuzzy about what is happening at a deeper level.

Comment: since `MyFloat` is mutable(not an isbits type), [deepcopy](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/a898a5049b850256b76ea726354c5b426108fe50/base/deepcopy.jl#L62-L75) does a bunch of other stuff.  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28183232/reproducing-a-population-should-i-deepcopy-each-individual), op said he deepcopied **more data than need**, I don't think the same solution can be applied to your example.

Comment: try changing `type MyFloat` in the definition to `immutable MyFloat` or `struct MyFloat` (the keyword changed in 0.6). This makes the times almost equal

Comment: @Gnimuc Thanks for the reference. Fascinating how much extra stuff gets done when the input is mutable!

Comment: @DanGetz Yep, spot on, that's what I should be doing. Many thanks.

Comment: @DanGetz please post your comment as an answer, so this question can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `type MyFloat` in the definition to `immutable MyFloat` or `struct MyFloat` (the keyword changed in 0.6). This makes the times almost equal.

As @Gnimuc mentioned, a mutable, which is not a bitstype, makes Julia keep track of a lot of other stuff. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28183232/reproducing-a-population-should-i-deepcopy-each-individual) and in the comments.